# AWS Redshift - Nested JSON Parsing

Tags: json, amazon-redshift

We are looking to parse a similar JSON data in redshift, the approach is to make use of super data type which will allow to parse nested JSON's in a easier manner, however while executing the below - we are not any records in the output

Tried different ways not able to get through - any pointers would be helpful.

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stage.string_json_tb
(
json_text VARCHAR(65535) ENCODE lzo
,jid INTEGER ENCODE az64
,json_super SUPER ENCODE zstd
)
DISTSTYLE AUTO

insert into stage.string_json_tb
(json_text, jid, json_super)
values ('{"r_nations":[
      {
         "n_comment":" haggle. carefully final deposits detect slyly agai",
         "n_nationkey":0,
         "n_name":"ALGERIA"
      },
      {
         "n_comment":"ven packages wake quickly. regu",
         "n_nationkey":5,
         "n_name":"ETHIOPIA"
      }
      
   ]}', '4', json_parse('{"r_nations":[
      {
         "n_comment":" haggle. carefully final deposits detect slyly agai",
         "n_nationkey":0,
         "n_name":"ALGERIA"
      },
      {
         "n_comment":"ven packages wake quickly. regu",
         "n_nationkey":5,
         "n_name":"ETHIOPIA"
      }
      
   ]}'))

select c.*, d  from stage.string_json_tb c, c.json_super d
          where jid =4
```

One more info, in reality the original json is something like follows, however per our understanding this is complex in nature to parse (given that the keys "1", "2" will be dynamic in nature) and hence better approach would be to provide an list of array elements as mentioned above. Need clarity on whether this is a correct understanding.

```
{"r_nations":{
      "1": {
         "n_comment":" haggle. carefully final deposits detect slyly agai",
         "n_nationkey":0,
         "n_name":"ALGERIA"
      },
      "2": {
         "n_comment":"ven packages wake quickly. regu",
         "n_nationkey":5,
         "n_name":"ETHIOPIA"
      }
     }
   }
```

Comment: So are you parsing super data that is embedded in SQL with no table table (compute node information)?

Comment: The json string is stored in a column in database table, just for reference / trying out, I had extracted and put into a CTE. Compute node information is as follows: dc2.large | 1 node. But does that have a impact?

Comment: Even though you have a single node "cluster" the Redshift code is still separated between leader and compute.  Since you are getting a "not supported" on "leader node" error I suspect that this is the issue with your "test code".  Try putting the data in a temp table which will be stored on the "compute" side.

Comment: I have created a table and inserted the same data into one of the columns - currently while there is no error, the query executed successfully and does not return any rows.

`select c.*, d  from stage.string_json_tb c, c.json_super d
          where jid =2`

The table contains three columns - json_text (varchar), jid, json_super (super).

The Json present in both the columns are same from the original question - first code block which i had given, only data type is different between these two columns.

Comment: Can you update the question with the DDL and creation SQL for this table?  I don't understand what jid is.

Comment: jid is simply an unique identifier for the records which was created, as we were trying to work out with different JSON formats . I have updated the original question with the DDL and insert data script.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, my initial node in the input json was not an array, and hence this should be the query to traverse,

```
select e  from stage.string_json_tb c, c.json_super.r_nations e
          where jid =2
```

Thanks so much Bill Weiner for the question and also helping in resolving the original error related to leader and pointing in the right direction.